# Jquery UI draggable wont drag first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image which when `onmousedown` is triggered, it runs a function that changes its class and makes it draggable, however the first time I drag it it wont drag, it changes the class but will not drag? After the intial failed drag, if you then drag again it will drag but why wont it drag at first?

```
function element_click(element_class) {
  $("#" + element_class).draggable("enable");
  $("." + element_class).addClass("element_select");
  $("#" + element_class).draggable({
    disabled: false,
    opacity: 0.9,
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(".element_select").removeClass('element_select');
      $("#" + element_class).addClass(element_class);
      $("#" + element_class).draggable("disable");
    }
  });
}


<img id="element_air_1" style="z-index: 5;" class="element_air_1" 
 onmousedown="javascript: element_click('element_air_1')" 
src="Doodle God Elements/air.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this block of code to your script:

```
window.onload = function(){
    element_click($('#element_air_1').attr('class'));   
}
```

It will trigger your script before your first click.

Comment: Thanks, now the real problem I have is trying to do this because all the class names and ids are loaded out of the database, but I'll figure something out, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You're meant to make it draggable *once* when it's added to the DOM, *before* it gets dragged for the first time.

Comment: I reckon this explanation solves the bigger problem, thanks